# Configure Mongoid relation to return objects sorted

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid, dsl

I have two classes with a 1-n relationship. Like so:

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :members
end

class Member
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :joined, type: Date
  belongs_to :band
end
```

Now when I call `band.members` I get the member objects. What I want is that if I call `band.members.last` to get the member who joined the last. I achieve this by defining the `<=>` method for `Member` and sort based on `joined`:

```
band.members.sort.last
```

How can I make this behavior default? I don't want to avoid the extra call to sort. Is this possible and if yes, how?

Comment: "I don't want to avoid the extra call to sort"? I don't follow. Why not just add a method that does what you want with a clear method name?

Comment: @WiredPrairie That's my current solution. I have a method `latest_band_member` which executes `band.members.sort.last`. I wondered if this can be automated through the Mongoid DSL.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  has_many :members, :order => :joined.asc
end
```